# VM instance and all the other settings at free google account wiped out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have a free trial google cloud account. This account was created when google was offering 1 year free trial period. All of a sudden the VM instance and all the other settings have disappeared. The account is still showing the balance of 29 days and $97.00. It is not understood that what has happened and how it can be recovered.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It appears that you upgraded your account to `paid` and then had a billing problem. You did not fix the billing problem, so Google suspended your account. Once Google suspends your account, they can delete your data since you are not paying for your account. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#add_a_new_payment_method_after_your_account_has_been_suspended

Comment: *@Shaf* could you confirm suggestion of *@John Hanley*?

Comment: This is not the case. The account is still free.

Comment: Have you tried to reach [Free Trial Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)?